# SQL Group By query - get related fields of aggregate function

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate

Simplified, but for a table like:

```
 id time distance price
 1  20   500      8 
 2  50   500      10 
 3  90   500      12 
 4  80   1000     17 
 5  170  1000     11 
 6  180  1000     13 
 7  19   800      12
```

I want to get the rows with the quickest time for the distances 500 and 1000, i.e.

```
 id time distance price
 1  20   500      8 
 4  80   1000     17
```

If I do

```
select min(time) from table
```

that works fine for finding the price, but I can't get the id and price - only the max/min/average/first value of all ids/prices.

I can do it with multiple look ups - e.g.

```
select * from table where distance = 500 and time = 20 
select * from table where distance = 1000 and time = 80
```

but is there a better way that doesn't involve 1 + (number of distances) queries (or at least provides one resultset, even if internally it uses that number of queries)

Comment: What do you want to do in the case of ties for the fastest time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use an inner select:

```
SELECT t.id, t.time, t.distance, t.price
FROM table t
JOIN (SELECT MIN(time) as min_time, distance
        FROM table
        GROUP BY distance) as tmp
      ON (t.distance = tmp.distance AND t.time = tmp.min_time)
WHERE t.distance IN (500, 1000)
```

Comment: This seems almost perfect for my needs. The one issue for me is that if I do have multiple entries for, say, distance 1000 and time 240 they'll both show up, whereas I only want one (maybe the first, maybe the last). However, I can probably get around this easily enough either by wrapping it in (yet) another query or just handle it in the application itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the min stuff into a having clause, so your query would be `select * from table group by distance having min(distance);`
(untested)
or you could use subquerys to find that out:
`select * from table where distance = (select distance from table where min(time)) and time = select min(time) from table)` (also untested :))

Comment: I Think this HAVING clause is meaningless (tested it...)

Answer (score 0):

What about this one ... gies exactly what you are looking for (TESTED)

```
select *  from Table1 where time in (select min(time)  from table1 where distance = 500 or distance = 1000 group by distance) and (distance = 500 or distance = 1000)
```

Comment: This will return only one record, and maybe none. the Minimum time in the table can be for another distance (e.g. 100) and nothing will be returned.

Comment: This still has the issue whereby it will get all results where time is the same as the correct distance - e.g. if there is a distance of 1001 and it has the same time as an entry with distance 1000 then it will be selected.

Answer (score 0):

just order by and limit. then you have the fastest for the 500 distance in 1 query.

```
select * from thetable where distance = 500 ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: He will still need multiple queries to get the records for several distances.

Comment: A union all can be employed if that's an issue. select * from thetable where distance = 500 ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 1 UNION ALL 
select * from thetable where distance = 1000 ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table1 t1
  JOIN (SELECT distance, MIN(time) min_time FROM table11 WHERE distance = 500 OR distance = 1000 GROUP BY distance) t2
    ON t1.distance = t2.distance AND t1.time = t2.min_time;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tblData INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(TIME) AS minTime, distance FROM tblData WHERE distance IN (500,1000) GROUP BY distance) AS subQuery ON tblData.distance = subQuery.distance AND tblData.time = subQuery.minTime
```